# Types FileResult and FileStreamResult are undefined, how do I fix that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have been looking at this since last night and just can't figure out how to resolve it.

2 errors, one says, `Type FileResult is not defined`.

The other says, `Type FileStreamResult is not defined`.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text
Imports EO.Pdf
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Partial Class getRecs
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Function Download() As FileResult
        ' Populate list with urls 
        Dim qParams As String = Request.QueryString("p")
        Dim urls() As String = qParams.Split(","c, ChrW(StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

        Dim documents = New List(Of EO.Pdf.PdfDocument)()
        For Each url In urls
            Dim doc = New EO.Pdf.PdfDocument()
            EO.Pdf.HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc)
            documents.Add(doc)
        Next

        Dim mergedDocument As EO.Pdf.PdfDocument = EO.Pdf.PdfDocument.Merge(documents.ToArray())

        Dim ms = New MemoryStream()
        mergedDocument.Save(ms)
        ms.Position = 0

        Return New FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf") With { _
         .FileDownloadName = "download.pdf" _
        }
    End Function

End Class
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to put MVC code into a WebForms project?

Comment: @J.Steen MVC and WebForms will mix in the same project quite happily.

Comment: @Richard Quite, but that would explain the missing imports, as you've answered. Just trying to lead the OP to their own solution. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you are missing a

```
Imports System.Web.Mvc
```

and possibly a reference to the `System.Web.Mvc` assembly. Doesn't VS provider a little drop down on the undefined symbols that will add this for you? (I rarely use VB, so not sure whether you get the same as C# for this.)

However for ASP.NET WebForms you might find [`HttpResponse.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx) a better approach.

Comment: yes VS does provide a little dropdown. It gave 2 suggestions for fixing FileResult. It says either create a class for FileResult or new Type. I selected "Create a Class" and the error for FileResult went away but I tried all suggestions for FileStreamResult but the error is still there.

Comment: @Kenny Have you checked you have the assembly reference?

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, I did check but don't see one. Can I do without these fileResult/FileStreamResult stuff? I actually found the sample code that I used here:

http://www.kristofclaes.be/

Using it to try and get the snippet here to work:

http://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/4/htmltopdf/merge.aspx

Comment: First, thanks a lot @Richard and thanks to all for your help and patience. I decided to force a save to the server. It seems to work. However, I still have a couple of problems. One is getting all the parameters passed to the url to render.

Please see update code. Assuming that the value of p is 12345. It adds it to the url but then 2 ugly things happen. 1, it adds a comma after the value(see below).

http://default.html?pin=12345,&mode=print&o=N&s=0.4

2, it chops off most if it showing only the following:

http://default.html?pin=12345. I tried httpUtility.HTMLEncode. It did not help.

Comment: @Kenny Either you or I is very confused. When I did the update to my question I had re-read your code. If you are deriving from `Page` you are using WebForms: returning `FileResult` is going to fail: methods that process the page lifecycle do not return content to the user agent with their return values: hence my update. But also if you are returning a file's content you won't be returning a URL, and there is nothing in the shown code to generate a URL. Suggest: strip out the MVC bits and stick with WriteFile.

Answer (score 2):

Both [`FileResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) and [`FileStreamResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult.aspx) need the following reference:

```
System.Web.Mvc
```